# Add rel="img" to a *.jpg link function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I`ve been using a Wordpress function, that adds a rel="img" to every link within a page that ends with *.jpg

```
<?php

// Attach a rel to linked images (for fancyBox)

function give_linked_images_rel($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){
  $rels = 'img';

  if ( preg_match('/<a.*? rel=".*?">/', $html) ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*? rel=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $rels . '$2', $html);
  } else {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 rel="' . $rels . '" >', $html);
  }
  return $html;
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_rel',10,8);

?>
```

This works fine on a server running php 5.2, using it on a 5.3 server does not seem to work. I guess there is a problem with the ?> in line 8 (probablly terminates the code?).

I`m  a total newbie to php, so I need a simple solution!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What happens in 5.3? Do you see an error?

Comment: I don`t have permission to the "log". It`s a basic webhost.